# CMS Connect, Community and Page tracking

Tags: reporting, customer-community, google-analytics

Looking for some general insight into how to solve a unique request. A client is looking to bring content from their blog into a Community and we're looking to leverage CMS Connect in order to accomplish this.

However, the client is wanting to know how many page views each blog post gets from the community members themselves. Basically, how is the blog content resonating with their community audience.

Being as we're dynamically pulling the content into the community using the CMS Connect feature, I'm unsure as to how we'd track the traction the blogs are getting within the Community itself.

I know the new integration with Google Analytics 360 integration coming sometime this year, we might be able to connect Leads/Contacts with Analytics data but am not sure if this would be the best solution.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The current google analytics integration feature in lightning communities should help to get these statistics.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_g_a_enable.htm&type=5

Whenever a user visits the blog detail page in a community, it should send the event to GA and you could use one of the existing page view report or you could create a custom report yourself in GA.

Instructions to install standard reports in GA:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_g_a_installation.htm&type=5

Note that this will track only the page views on detail page.